# How to stitch two video with FFmpeg in Android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

There are two video, I want to stitch them with FFmpeg in Android likes the following picture, does any one can help me or give me some advice?Thanks!

[One video on left, the other on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBj85.png)

Comment: See [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) filter.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you!